# Generalization of pentomino-rectangle tiling

Tags: 3d, tiling, polyomino

It is very well known that there are $12$ pentominos and they can tile $6 \times 10$, $5 \times 12$, $4 \times 15$ and $3 \times 20$ rectangles. Now, let's define a function for simplify this.
$$t(n)=\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n$-ominos tile rectangle} \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$
$t(5)=1$. Also, one can prove that $t(6)=t(4)=0$ by "checkboard coloring". It is obvious that $t(n)=0$ for $n \ge 7$ since at least one of $n$-omino contains a hole.

By simple brute force, $t(1)=t(2)=1$, $t(3)=0$.

**Question.** Is there any higher-dimensional researches about this? For example, is it possible to tile $4 \times 4 \times 2$ cube with $8$ possible $4$-polycubes?

Comment: $t(n)=1$ if it is possible to tile any rectangle using exactly 1 of each $n$-omino

Comment: Yes, my mistake @RossMillikan

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is something people have studied, but after playing around for a few minutes I found this (a-h represent the eight tiles):

\begin{align}
\text{a a a a} \\
\text{b d e c} \\
\text{d d d f} \\
\text{h h h f} \\
\\
\text{b b c c} \\
\text{b e e c} \\
\text{g g e f} \\
\text{h g g f} \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question, as it allows me to mention one of my favourite combinatorial geometry results of all time, which I first read about on the great [*Combinatorics and More*](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/).

Consider the fact that an $n$-omino can be represented as a connected set of $n$ points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. The result said that given *any* such set of points in $\mathbb{Z}^m$, for arbitrary $m>0$, there exists a $k\geq m$ such that the $n$-omino *tiles* $\mathbb{Z}^k$! So, any *q*-dimensional *n*-omino tiles an entire space in some dimension!

*Remarkable*! You can read about this [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49915/does-every-polyomino-tile-rn-for-some-n).